# Azure kubernetes and active directory connection

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-active-directory, azure-load-balancer, kubernetes-cluster

I am trying to connect my active directory with my kubernetes cluster. I have a webapp (asp.net) in a container registry and I want my users to login with active directory.
I also have a load balancer after the cluster.

What Redirect URI do I need in my Active Directory settings?
The load balancer has a http URI and the AAD needs https. I tried a gateway with certificate, but that didnt work.

Is a CoreDNS in the kubernetes cluster a posible solution, to connect my aad with kubernetes?

I would be very thankful for every answer.

Comment: Have you checked this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-ad-integration-cli

Comment: my Active directory is on an other directory without subscription. Do you know how I can get a domain from kubernetes to add it to de redirect url from the active directory?